# Delphi XE modeling - 'Open diagram' is disabled

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to use modeling but when I right click on the name of the project in 'Model view', the 'Open diagram' is disabled.
How to enable it?

---

Of course, modeling support is enabled:
 * The whole 'Model view' panel is there.
 * TGIDE150.bpl is present in HKEY_CURRENT_USER...\Known IDE Packages.
 * If I right click on TForm1 in Model View I see the 'Select on diagram' option which is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. All functionality is there but it cannot be used because the 'Open diagram' menu is disabled all the time. However, it works if you use the alternative approach. So, obviously it is a Delphi bug (oh my God, I used again words Delphi and bug together - some Delphi users will get really pissed off, again).

**Solution:**

The 'Open diagram' is always disabled, but I see that I can still open the diagram by simply double clicking the items/nodes in 'Model View'.
TAaaa-DAaaa! Solved.

---

Update:

Damn! Now the 'Generate sequence diagram' is disabled. I need to find an alternative way to access it...